# Click on twitter 'Next' button using selenium on python

Tags: python, selenium, twitter, selenium-chromedriver

twitter updated and now my sign in is broken, I tried different methods like xpath and css selector but both didn't work so i'm stuck on the first part of the [login](https://twitter.com/login). The command in my script looks something like this:

```
signinbtn = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#layers > div:nth-child(2) > div > div > div > div > div > div.css-1dbjc4n.r-1awozwy.r-18u37iz.r-1pi2tsx.r-1777fci.r-1xcajam.r-ipm5af.r-g6jmlv > div.css-1dbjc4n.r-1867qdf.r-1wbh5a2.r-kwpbio.r-rsyp9y.r-1pjcn9w.r-1279nm1.r-htvplk.r-1udh08x > div > div > div.css-1dbjc4n.r-14lw9ot.r-6koalj.r-16y2uox.r-1wbh5a2 > div.css-1dbjc4n.r-16y2uox.r-1wbh5a2.r-1jgb5lz.r-1ye8kvj.r-13qz1uu > div > div > div > div:nth-child(6) > div > span > span')))
signinbtn.click()
```

but it gives me

```
  File "C:\Users\drumm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

EDIT: I had easy time filling out my username btw so I hope theres a way to click on the button.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using relative xpath: `//span[text()='Next']`

You code look like:

```
signinbtn = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(By.XPATH,'//span[text()='Next']'))
signinbtn.click()
```